# How do I get NSDragOperation to IBAction

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, ibaction

I have a NSDragOperation that currently resides in a different implementation as AppDelegate; it grabs the file name of a dragged file and populates a text field on AppDelegate. From that text field the user can press 'ok' to try and process the file grabbed from the drag operation. How do I skip the user interaction and automatically try and process the file?

I tried such things as:

```
[AppDelegate button:(id)sender];
```

The result is:

```
(Error: Use of undeclared identifier 'sender')
```

I think I'm on the right track, although I seem to have trouble with these type operations were I want to auto submit an IBAction, so it would be nice to know how to do it. Thanks...

Comment: ... "populates a text field on AppDelegate" – how?